# Read a file and do a copy

Tags: batch-file

The following script runs fine at CMD *prompt*

```
FOR /F "delims=" %R IN (C:\Test01.txt) DO IF Ready == %R COPY /y C:\Test01.txt "D:\Ready.txt"
```

File is copied succesfully to D drive if the text01 file as 'Ready' as one of the line,
But create a BAT file with the same script its failing with the following error

```
R was unexpected at this time.
```

Any idea to fix the bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double `%` (e.g. `%%R`) notation in bat files for variables.

Correct command is,

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%R IN (C:\Test01.txt) DO IF Ready == %%R COPY /y C:\Test01.txt "D:\Ready.txt"
```

[For Syntax](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** %R can be used only in command line. In a batch file, variables have to be %%R.

Please read this for more info http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php